# ndsolve interpolatingfunctions not shown/evaluated

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, interpolation

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9000235/2283226) technique from Simon, I want to solve a matrix differential equation with a matrix that contains an explicit time-dependence(our variable), but I want to be able to solve this problem for a generic number of functions `K+1` thus auto-indexing them. My code, stripped of a few things which don't seem to be the problem, (with I= imaginary unit):

```
K=2;

dl = ConstantArray[ 1/2 Exp[-I t], K];       %defining M
dm = Array[(# - 1)^2 &, K + 1];
dr = ConstantArray[1/2 Exp[I t], K];
M = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> dr, Band[{1, 1}] -> dm, 
Band[{2, 1}] -> dl}] // Normal

a[t_] := Table[g[k][t], {k, 0, K}]          %defining a as a list of functions g

NDSolve[{a'[t] == I *M.a[t], g[0][0] == 0, g[1][0] == 1, g[2][0] == 0}, {g[0], g[1], g[2]}, {t, 0, 10}][[1, All, 2]] //Abs
%solving the diff. eq.
```

Which returns a list of three InterpolatingFunctions with output scalar as I would expect. However,

```
Plot[%,{t,0,10}]
```

Only draws axes without any graphs. But I solved these equations for K=2 beforehands in another way(but still with DSolve) and saw some results which should also be shown the domain of this graph, but are missing. Similarly, function evaluation for a random value of t

```
%%[1]
```

Doesn't give a number either.

My intention when this works for a generic K is add a manipulate to change some parameters I put equal to one now and make the whole thing a function of K.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Just a reminder: `(*comments look like this in Mathematica*)`, single line comments aren't really used. The answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1498/20144) provides some discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{a'[t] == I*M.a[t], g[0][0] == 0, g[1][0] == 1, 
                    g[2][0] == 0}, {g[0], g[1], g[2]}, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[Abs /@ Through[sol[t]], {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @belisarius is forth.
A curious thing however is that Evaluated is not in the documentation as an option for plot

Comment: @Wouter 1) See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11772/193 2) Learn how to upvote answers